# Pull for new results inside jQuery's getJSON

Tags: jquery, getjson

I'm working on adding a way to pull for results in my [jQuery.JamCity](https://github.com/bluetidepro/jQuery.JamCity).

Right now, it uses `getJSON` to pull api data from Last.Fm each `$.each` to parse through that data and output it.

I want to make it so that it checks for new results ever minute and `IF` there is a new item in `data[0]` to display it but `ELSE`, don't do anything because I don't want to just keep having the recent song pop-up.

**How would I go about doing this?** I imagine I use something like `setInterval` but I don't fully get how that works. Any code examples or ideas on how to achieve this functionality?

Comment: it would be nice if you produced a small chunk of relevant code as your starting point. the stuff on your repo is too big to try to grok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is some starting code that would do this:

```
var lastSong = null;
var fetch = function(){
   $.getJSON('....', function(data) {
       if(data.length) {
           currentSong = data[0].some_unique_id
           if(lastSong != currentSong){
              //put code here to play song
              lastSong = currentSong;
           }
       }  
       setTimeout(fetch, 1000 * 60);
   });
}
fetch();
```

Comment: Using your example here, I got the general idea and am currently getting to the point of making it do what I want! Thanks so much for your snippet! :)

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` takes a function and a timeout interval (x) in milliseconds as in input. Once set interval is specified, after x milliseconds the function will be called.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval

That is indeed how you would want to code this functionality. Simply create a function that calls `getJSON` to get your data with an interval of 60000 (one minute).

After the call to `getJSON` returns, process the data accordingly to see if the results have changed from the last time the function was called.